# Как лучше сверстать элемент

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка

друзья! Недавно появилась задачка. Нужно сверстать вот такой блок как на картинке. Это радиокнопки. Слева не выбрана, справа выбрана. Как можно сверстать так, чтобы одну сторона изображения выезжала за бордер, а другая нет (скрывалась)? Может кто сталкивался с подобными задачами.

[image: блок выбора кол-ва продукта]

Comment: Не проще ли сделать 2 разные картинки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример 1

```css
input{
    display: none;
}
input + .image{
    display: block;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqwIV.jpg);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 205px;
    width: 264px;
    transition: background-position .3s ease;
}
input:checked + .image{
    background-position: -264px 0;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c">
    <span class="image"></span>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c">
    <span class="image"></span>
</label>
```

Пример 2

```css
label {
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.block__not-checked {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #999;
}

.block__checked {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

input:checked+.block .block__not-checked {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked+.block .block__checked {
  opacity: 1;
}

.block__icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: #01C92B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.block__circle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 4px solid #01C92B;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block__box,
.block__circle-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: -10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.block__box {
  right: auto;
  left: -20px;
  top: 45px;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c">
    <span class="block">
        <span class="block__not-checked"></span>
        <span class="block__checked">    
            <span class="block__icon">icon</span>
            <span class="block__box"></span>
            <span class="block__circle"> 
                <span class="block__circle-box"></span> 
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>    
</label>
```